# Strange issue with linking nodes in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-arrows

I have the following tree:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\geometry{a4paper}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style         = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, top color=blue!15, bottom color=blue!5, draw, align=center},
  code/.style             = {treenode, text width=1.5cm, font=\tiny},
  root/.style             = {code, top color=blue!45, bottom color=blue!15},
  qnode/.style            = {treenode}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tree layout, level distance=1.5cm]
\begin{scope}
  \node (root) [root] {Root}
    child { node (1) [qnode] {}
      child { node (11) {} }
      child { node (12) [qnode] {} }
      child { node (13) {} }
      child { node (14) [qnode] {} }
    }
    child { node (2) [qnode] {} }
    child { node (3) [qnode] {}
      child { node (31) [qnode] {} }
      child { node (32) [qnode] {} }
      child { node (33) [qnode] {} }
      child { node (34) [qnode] {}
        child { node (341) [qnode] {} }
        child { node (342) {} }
        child { node (343) {} }
        child { node (344) [qnode] {} }
      }
    }
    child { node (4) {} }
  ;
  \draw[->, dashed] (344) -- (334);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However when I typset this with LuaLaTeX I get

```
No shape named 12 is known
```

Whatever I change the second shape to (in this example "12") I get that the second shape is not known.

What am I doing wrong? Or **less** preferably: How else can I draw an arrow between the 2 node and the 12 node

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please provide complete minimal working example, which begin with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. In your your snippet aren't defined `root` and `qnode` style for nodes. In general it is bad idea to use numbers for node names.

Comment: @Zarko I have added the extra bits to make the code a MWE, on the point about naming with numbers I seem to get this issue with letters (1=>a,2=>b,...) also, any ideas?

Comment: Try comment`\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees}` and `tree layout`, also the `scope` is surplus (but it doesn't harm) and for dashed line select existing name (334 isn't defined). With this changes your MWE work at me.

Comment: Actually, it is sufficient to comment  ` tree layout` option in TikZ picture. Seems that three layout doesn't allow to naming nodes.

Comment: @Zarko I may be missing something but this doesn't seem to help for me.

Comment: You should consider **forest**. I'd post an answer except that you've said that you don't want to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more extended comment than answer. I don' know background why you design simple tree on relative complicated way. With reducing your (non)MWE into:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[margin=1in, a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees}% it is not necessary for your tree
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes}
\title{Complex Equation Solver and Locus Plotter}
\author{Oliver Webb}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, 
                       top color=blue!15, bottom color=blue!5, draw, align=center},
    code/.style     = {treenode, text width=1.5cm, font=\tiny},
    root/.style     = {code, top color=blue!45, bottom color=blue!15},
    qnode/.style    = {treenode}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
%    tree layout, this cause your problem
    level distance=1.5cm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},% added for preventing overlap of nodes
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}% added for preventing overlap of node
                     ]
  \node (root) [root] {Root}
    child { node (n1) [qnode] {}
      child { node (11) {} }
      child { node (12) [qnode] {} }
      child { node (13) {} }
      child { node (14) [qnode] {} }
    }
    child { node (2) [qnode] {} }
    child { node (3) [qnode] {}
      child { node (31) [qnode] {} }
      child { node (32) [qnode] {} }
      child { node (33) [qnode] {} }
      child { node (34) [qnode] {}
        child { node (341) [qnode] {} }
        child { node (342) {} }
        child { node (343) {} }
        child { node (344) [qnode] {} }
      }
    }
    child { node (4) {} }
  ;
  \draw[->, dashed] (342) -- (343);% here is select one of existing nodes
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

works in LuaLatEX (contain in recent version of MikTeX):

[image]

If above MWE doesn't work for you, than should be some difference in used LuaLaTeX. Unfortunately, I don't use it, so in this I'm not able to help you.

Comment: Thank you @Zarko however the tree overlaps itself on level 2 which is why I was using tree layout and LuaLaTeX in the first place, however if this is the only way to go then I may have to find a workaround.

Comment: I sow this, and for resolve this you don't need `Lua ...`, You only need to select appropriate `sibling distance`. However, this was not your question. I will upgrade my "answer" accordingly.